# How to open file using its default program in python

Tags: python

How do I open a file from python? Not using the open() function and read or write, I mean simulate a user double clicking on the file. So if I open file1.jpg I want it to open using the default image program.

Thanks

Comment: u should import os, and use some appropriate tool... like xdg-open... i.e. _____  `os.system(dxg-open)`

Answer (score 3):

in linux you can use **xdg-open** like bellow:

```
from subprocess import call
call(['xdg-open','filename'])
```

Answer (score 0):

On windows, you get this behavior if you execute through the win32 shell. An easy way to do that is with the subprocess module:

```
import subprocess as subp
subp.call('file1.jpg', shell=True)
```